# Java match whole word in String

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I have an `ArrayList<String>` which I iterate through to find the correct index given a String. Basically, given a String, the program should search through the list and find the index where the whole word matches. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
foo.add("AAAB_11232016.txt");
foo.add("BBB_12252016.txt");
foo.add("AAA_09212017.txt");
```

So if I give the String `AAA`, I should get back index `2` (the last one). So I can't use the `contains()` method as that would give me back index `0`.

I tried with this code:

```
String str = "AAA";
String pattern = "\\b" + str + "\\b";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

for(int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++) {
    // Check each entry of list to find the correct value
    Matcher match = p.matcher(foo.get(i));

    if(match.find() == true) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code never reaches the `if` statement inside the loop. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note: This should also work if I searched for `AAA_0921`, the full name `AAA_09212017.txt`, or any part of the String that is unique to it.

Comment: `_` is considered a word character..so it wont act as word boundary..

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know that. I'll look into another expression.

Comment: Don't you mean `return i;`?

Comment: I did, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since word boundary does not match between a word char and underscore you need

```
String pattern = "(?<=_|\\b)" + str + "(?=_|\\b)";
```

Here, `(?<=_|\b)` positive lookbehind requires a word boundary or an underscore to appear before the `str`, and the `(?=_|\b)` positive lookahead requires an underscore or a word boundary to appear right after the `str`.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL1fA6/1).

If your word may have special chars inside, you might want to use a more straight-forward word boundary:

```
"(?<![^\\W_])" + Pattern.quote(str) + "(?![^\\W_])"
```

Here, the negative lookbehind `(?<![^\\W_])` fails the match if there is a word character except an underscore (`[^...]` is a negated character class that matches any character other than the characters, ranges, etc. defined inside this class, thus, it matches all characters other than a non-word char `\W` and a `_`), and the `(?![^\W_])` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a word char except the underscore after the `str`.

Note that the second example has a quoted search string, so that even `AA.A_str.txt` could be matched well with `AA.A`.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL1fA6/2)

Comment: Thank you very much! This made it work. Can you explain the different parts of the expression? I'm fairly new to `regex`. if not, that's alright, I can look it up.

Comment: @Flow One great tool is [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com). If you look in the top right panel, it explains the regex you give it. Granted, it doesn't support Java regex, but it is usually close enough to PCRE.

Comment: I am fighting with my son for the laptop in the train compartment, and I will try of course :)

Comment: Haha, I really appreciate it! @4castle Awesome, this will help greatly!

Comment: Does this support other languages as well?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan All those where the regex library supports lookarounds, both lookbehind and lookahead. What language/library are you interested in?

Comment: I am sorry. By language i mean Arabic. Does this support Arabic texts in any way?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan You just need to make `\b` Unicode aware, prepend the  pattern with `(?U)` (i.e. `"(?U)(?<=_|\\b)"`) or compile with the corresponding flag: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);`.