# How to find a word in a string in Java (keyword not included in another word)

Tags: java, string, keyword, cpu-word

I have to search a word in a Java String, but I don't know how to solve the following problem:

*Ex:*
keyword: car

text: I want to take **car**e of the cat.

The keyword appears in another word, but I don't want that to be detected. I want to detect only if the keyword isn't part of another word.

*Ex*
keyword: car

text: I have a new car. (CORRECT)

I can't search for " car " (with spaces before and after), because it can appear as "car." in the text (the end of the sentence), so it would still not detect the correct situations

Comment: Have a look at [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions). There is a simple java regex solution for your problem.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes from the `java.util.regex` package, which are a good place to start.

Comment: Possibly related: [Java match whole word in String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38229378)

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression consisting of the input `word` between word boundaries `\b` needs to be compiled, then create a `Matcher` of the `text`, and use `Matcher::find`:

```java
public static boolean containsWord(String text, String word) {
    return Patern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b").matcher(text).find();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `matches(".* … .*")` you might use `find("…")`

Comment: Yes, a few more letters to type for getting significantly better performance…

Comment: It’s easy to forget, but `text.matches(".*word.*")` has a different outcome than `Pattern.compile("word").matcher(text).find()` when `text` contains line breaks. Usually, the latter is matching the actual intention. I should have mentioned it first, but even I sometimes forget…